# Incluir tarefa no agendador de tarefas do Windows via batch

Tags: windows, batch, cmd, agendamento

Faço a configuração de diversos tipos de backups por batch, os códigos não são pertinentes a essa pergunta, porém o que dá trabalho é sempre configurá-los pelo Agendador de Tarefas do Windows.

Existe algumas forma de adicionar essas tarefas por batch?

Gostaria de poder configurar no batch:

- Nome da tarefa;
- Diferentes horários de execução;
- Se é mensal ou diário;
- Ser executada somente quando o usuário estiver conectado ou não.

> Além de poder adicionar essa tarefa, seria interessante saber se ela
>   existe primeiro, porque nesse caso poderia fazer essa verificação na
>   primeira execução do backup manualmente por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o comando `at`.

```
at \\"nomedopc" 00:00 /interactive /every:m,t,w,th,f,s,su "\\nomedoarquivo.bat"
```

Não esqueça de autenticar na estação com algum usuário que pertença ao grupo **domain admin**, ou outro usuário que seja **administrador** local.

Ao executar o comando acima, ele cria uma tarefa agendada para executar às 00:00 todos os dias.

Comment: Deu essa mensagem: O comando AT foi preterido. Use schtasks.exe em seu lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, segue abaixo exemplo de comando. Você pode/deve também digitar no console:

```
schtasks /create /?
schtasks /change /?
schtasks /?
```

Exemplo:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /ST 12:10 /SC DAILY /TN Sistema_BackupERP /TR "C:\SISTEMA\BancoDeDados\appBackup\BackupBaseDeDados" /RL HIGHEST /F /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```

Tenho esta pergunta mais avançada em aberto:

[AGENDADOR DE TAREFAS VIA PROMPT DE COMANDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400721/)