# Criar Nome do Arquivo com Dia da Semana

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Preciso criar uma rotina que faça o **backup** com o **nome** do **dia** da **semana** no arquivo, de forma a obedecer o seguinte **layout**:

> **Exemplo:** backup_01012019_**segunda**.7z

O mais próximo que encontre e que não me ajudou, foi o código abaixo:

```
for /F "tokens=2 skip=2 delims=," %%D in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:csv') do @echo %%D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-**Update:** **+ Rápido** para **obtenção data**|**dia**|**semana** e ***compactada|encurtada*** no **código** :

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion & set "_do=Get Day^,Month^,Year^,DayOfWeek" 
(set "_ds=0Domingo,1Segunda,2Terca,3Quarta,4Quinta,5Sexta,6Sabado," && for /f "tokens=1-4delims= " %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime 
^!_do!^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "_d=0%%a" & set "_m=0%%c" & set "_data=!_d:~-2!_!_m:~-2!_%%~d" & set _x=%%b & for %%x in (!_ds!)do ^
echo/%%x|findstr /blic:!_x! >nul && (set "_s=%%x" & set "_data=!_data!_!_s:~1!")) & set "_backup_file=backup_!_data!.7z" & echo/!_backup_file!
```

---

**|** **Resulta** **|**  **<kbd>`backup_22_04_2019_Segunda.7z`</kbd>**

---

- **Bat** • Para **compor** o **layout** do **nome** do **arquivo** pegando os **dados** de **data (** com **"0"** na frente para **dia**/**mês** menor que **10)** e **adicionando** o **dia** da **semana** no **nome arquivo**

---

```bat
@echo off & @setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_dias_=0-Domingo,1-Segunda,2-Terca,3-Quarta,4-Quinta,5-Sexta,6-Sabado"

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims= " %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year^,DayOfWeek^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') do (
    if not %%a geq 10 (set "_data=0%%a") else (set "_data=%%~a")
    if not %%c geq 10 (set "_data=!_data: =!0%%c") else (set "_data=!_data: =!%%~c")
    set "_data=!_data!%%d" & set "DayOfWeek=%%b"
    )
for %%d in (!_dias_!)do for /F %%D in ('echo/!DayOfWeek!') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%1 in ('echo/%%d') do if "%%D" equ "%%1" set "_data=!_data!_%%2"&&goto :_next_:
    )

:_next_:
set _backup_file=backup_!_data!.7z
echo/ !_backup_file!
```

---

**|** **Resulta** **|**  **<kbd>`backup_22_04_2019_Segunda.7z`</kbd>**

---

Comment: Muito obrigado. Perfeito.

Comment: Obs. Caso queira o nome do dia da semana toda em minúsculas, eh soh editar a variável **_dias_**.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. A edição fica de boa para fazer.

Comment: Será que poderia me ajudar aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242536/incluir-tarefa-no-agendador-de-tarefas-do-windows-via-batch